# Xamarin.Android release build fails with 'STRING_TOO_LARGE' message

Tags: xamarin.android, release

We have a quite complex Xamarin.Android project that can be built using *Debug* version in Visual Studio 2019 v16.3.

Whenever I set it to build the *Release* version, I get this error:

> Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1657,2): error APT0000: string too
>   large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'.
>
> Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1657,2): error APT0000: string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead
>   as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'.

I checked our `strings.xml` file and replaced all the 'long' texts (more that 30 characters) with a single letter but the error persists. Also checked the `anim` and `drawable` xml files but they don't contain long paths or anything resembling a long string.

Unfortunately the error does not tell what the string is...

How should I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

We tried to build it on a separate machine and the error appears there as well. It seems that actually there is a very long string somewhere in the code. Who designed that error message and thought that it would be useful…?

Comment: try to clean you project ,delete the obj and bin file,and rebuild

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Tried but no effect. I found a quite long `pathData` (with 11k+ character) in one of the drawables but when I remove it, the error remains. Can I somehow find the exact one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that software can find what the human eye can't…

I've created a [Powershell script](https://gist.github.com/nestorium/0ca209a232f164db645293c3db749df0) to count the characters inside the files and turned out that we have 2 drawables with lengths *over 32k*.

When I truncated them the build was successful. Strange that we could release the software with Visual Studio 16.2.

Comment: Yeah, I just had to wait at least 48 hours.