# string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as ‘STRING_TOO_LARGE’ at Visual studio 2019 for Xamarin.android project

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

When I am building my project at visual studio 2019 at windows or Mac then the following error occurs. "string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'. The error is occurs at Visual studio 2019 16.7.7 for windows. But this error is not happening at visual studio 2017. But I need to compile my project to visual studio 2019. Project properties is given at below screenshot https://prnt.sc/zpbX_vz0gY7U.

I have xml files at resource folder but they are mot more than 2 KB/file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229987/android-studio-with-java-compiler-error-string-too-large-to-encode-using-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that some characters inside the files are **exceeding** the **maximum** length.Please try to find out these characters and manage to truncate them.Use this [PowerShell script](https://gist.github.com/nestorium/0ca209a232f164db645293c3db749df0).

Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58372687/xamarin-android-release-build-fails-with-string-too-large-message).